# Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommLayer, Version=13.0.2000.0

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I have developed a simple project. where i have to print some crystal report. the project runs very well in local machine, but when i up this on a web hosting server, it shows me an error when crystal report viewing.

> Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommLayer, Version=13.0.2000.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>       Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load
>   file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommLayer,
>   Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304'
>   or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to
>   determine why the assembly
>   'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommLayer, Version=13.0.2000.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' could not be loaded.
>
> WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF. To enable assembly bind
>   failure logging, set the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1. Note: There
>   is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure
>   logging. To turn this feature off, remove the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

Please any one can help me .....

Comment: 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.dll' assembly is not uploaded with your application. On local server they are presented in GAC

Comment: Try using this url i am studied lot of blogs finally found this
in this you can find your required version download it and try it
it will more helpfull to you
https://downloads.i-theses.com/index.php?option=com_downloads&task=downloads&groupid=9

Answer (score 17):

I had the same error after moving to a new laptop (Windows 10).  In addition to setting Copy Local to true as mentioned above, I had to install the Crystal Reports 32-bit runtime engine for .Net Framework, even though everything else is set to run in a 64-bit environment.  Hope that helps.

[image: Windows Control Panel - Programs and Features]

Comment: Is it possible to avoid installing this runtime https://stackoverflow.com/q/46073843/196526 ?

Comment: https://support.jeff-net.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/57/0/installingreinstalling-crystal-reports-runtime-engine-manually

Comment: Installing the Crystal Reports 32-bit solved my problem

Comment: During design time (in Visual Studio) Crystal Reports design tools run as 32bit to match the Visual Studio bitness.  So even if you are developing a 64bit app, you need to install the 32 bit version of Crystal Reports runtime for Visual Studio.  However, you only need to deploy the 64bit versions with your app.

Comment: I ran into a similar situation and what resolved it was installing both the 64bit and 32bit runtime on the web server; and ensuring the IIS_ISRS had read, write permission to C:\Windows\Temp folder.  I did not have to add the crystaldecisions.reportappserver.commlayer.dll to the bin folder as I believe it is in the GAC when you install the two runtimes.

Answer (score 13):

As I said in comment your `crystaldecisions.reportappserver.commlayer.dll` is not copied / present on your server. So for this you have to manually copy the dll and paste into you `Bin` folder

To copy a `DLL` from visual studio project follow the steps

> 1.Expand your **Project's** References hierarchy (Project should not be in debug mod)
>
> 2.Right Click on Particular `Dll` (in your case `crystaldecisions.reportappserver.commlayer.dll`) and select Properties and set 'Copy Local' attribute to **TRUE**
>
> 3 Build your project. The Dll should be there in your `BIN` Folder.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "Right Click on Particular dll". From Visual Studio? The dll or the reference? Where do you find the reference then? From Nuget? Which package? Sorry to ask all this but I have same issue and I really cannot find crystaldecisions.reportappserver.commlayer.dll

Comment: @B413 first check if you have reference of `crystaldecisions.reportappserver.commlayer.dl` under your project's references in solution explorer, if you don't have reference then add it, then follow above steps.

Comment: Despite having all the above settings in place...still i am facing same issue...any suggestion would be great

Comment: @Prathyush is this the same issue? please check whether the relevant  DLL are present in your bin directory after build or publishing the solution.

Comment: @KanisXXX thanks for your response. Problem was with IIS setting, instead of 64 bit in app pool we had 32 bit application "true".

Answer (score 8):

I faced the same issue and used the following steps to solve it

1) go Right side in solution explorer
2) Click on your `Project Name`
3) click on `Reference`
4) you can see yellow symbol on some DLL
5) Right click on that DLL and go to `Property`
6) Find `Specific Version = True` replace it with `Specific Version = False`

and also change `Copy Local = False`  to `Copy Local = True`

Comment: I select all reference files at once and applied steps. Problem solved thanks

Comment: This led to the fix for me; but I did use @KanisXXX answer to troubleshoot/test the issue first,  and then being able to set Copy Local was dependent on changing Embed Interop Types first, as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15526491/why-is-the-copy-local-property-for-my-reference-disabled.
and, of course, once I'd fixed commlayer, I had to do the same for my other dlls.

Answer (score 5):

CR has changed the Version No of Assemblies. The Old Version is 13.0.2000.0 (this is a incompatible version problem). The New Version is 13.0.3500.0 or 13.0.4000.0 - this is for my test case of Visual Studio 2019 and .net 4.7.2 and Window Server 2019. You need to open all your projects, Remove the old dll reference and add the new references. Then build the application again.

I learnt from source:

- Best Answer: https://answers.sap.com/questions/303438/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-%27crystaldecisionsr.html
- Installation Notes
  Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2017:
  https://www.tektutorialshub.com/crystal-reports/crystal-reports-download-for-visual-studio/#Service-Pack-16

[image]

TO remove: Right click on an assembly under references to remove it.

[image]

This is where the error comes from - it is exactly what the error message outputs:

error message:

> Could not load file or assembly ... The located assembly's manifest
>   definition does not match the assembly reference ...

location error message referring to:

> "C:\Visual-Studio-2019-Proj\Proj Windows Inventory\Proj Windows
>   Inventory\obj\x86\Debug\Press HDL Windows Inventory.exe.manifest"

And it looks like this:

-The older version of .net 3.5 and CReports version="13.0.2000.0" and VS2012:

```
<dependentAssembly dependencyType="install" allowDelayedBinding="true" codebase="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll" size="372736">
      <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine" version="13.0.2000.0" publicKeyToken="692FBEA5521E1304" language="neutral" processorArchitecture="msil" />
```

-The newer version of .net 4.7.2 and CReport version="13.0.4000.0" and VS2019:

```
<dependentAssembly dependencyType="install" allowDelayedBinding="true" codebase="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll" size="373248">
      <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine" version="13.0.4000.0" publicKeyToken="692FBEA5521E1304" language="neutral" processorArchitecture="msil" />
```

Comment: This helped me a lot! One member of my team didn't have crystal decisions intalled, he was using from nuget package and everytime he was trying to deploy it was crashing.
I figured out that his DLL was pointing to Package folder while all the others were pointing to sap business folder.

Thanks!

Comment: this comment helped a lot. how can we use Crystal runtime 64 bits? can you help me?

Answer (score 3):

Edit Web Config for each CrystalDecisions file version make it same version of the .dll file (Right-click on it and select properties within solution explorer)
For example.
crystaldecisions.reportappserver.commlayer.dll --> 13.0.2000.0
after upgrade crystal report to  CRforVS_13_0_21 edit it to ---> 13.0.3500.0

Comment: This was the solution to our problem, however our filename reference was different than the OP.  In our case we had the same base error but the filename reference was: "Assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0". So, changing the version to the version of the actual matching DLL fixed us.

Comment: I Also had the same issue, just change the version to the right one in the web.config

Answer (score 2):

Somehow I had the wrong versions of the DLLs registered in my project.

- I removed the three references to the Crystal Report dlls from my project.
  [image: Crystal DLLs]
- I right click References, and click Add Reference
- In the popup window, I click the Browse menu on the left and the Browse button
  [image: Reference Manager]
- In the Directory window where your DLLs reside (perhaps your application's bin directory), select the three Crystal Reports DLLs and then click Add.
  [image: DLLs]
- Back at the Reference Manager window, click in the first column to the left of the three Crystal dlls, and then click OK
  [image]
- At this point your Crystal Reports should work again.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue when move to new laptop and used the following steps to solve it

- Close the project
- Install [SAP Crystal Reports 13.0 runtime (32-bit)](https://downloads.i-theses.com/index.php?option=com_downloads&task=downloads&groupid=9&id=100) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtqpM.jpg)
- Delete the project .suo file
- Open the Project and first built the project
- Now after running the project issue is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

In the first plate you have to check that:

- 1) You install a appropriate version of Crystal Reports SDK =>

  `http://downloads.i-theses.com/index.php?option=com_downloads&task=downloads&groupid=9&id=101` (for example)
- 2) Add reference to dll  =>
  `crystaldecisions.reportappserver.commlayer.dll`

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2022 and Runtime CR 13 SP32 With IIS and getting error

> Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

[image]

Resolved:

1. Go to **IIS**
2. Click **Application Pools**
3. Right-click your application pools (same site browser)
4. Choose **Advanced Setting**
5. Change "**Enable 32-Bit Applications**" to "**False**"
6. Click **OK**
7. Restart your site browser

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For me it was "Prefer 32bit": clearing the checkbox allowed CLR to load Crystal Reports 64bit runtime (the only one installed).

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the DLL copied to your project and the Copy Local flag is in true, the solution should be just rebuild the project. That will copy the DLL to the bin folder.

Answer (score 0):

```
For visual studio 2019 
change the code in aspx.cs page

    <%@ Register Assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.4000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"
        Namespace="CrystalDecisions.Web" TagPrefix="CR" %>

in web config:

    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="businessObjects">
          <sectionGroup name="crystalReports">
            <section name="rptBuildProvider" type="CrystalDecisions.Shared.RptBuildProviderHandler, CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=13.0.4000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, Custom=null"/>
          </sectionGroup>
        </sectionGroup>
      </configSections>


 <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=13.0.4000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportSource, Version=13.0.4000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=13.0.4000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.4000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc, Version=13.0.4000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
        <add assembly="System.Management, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"/>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=13.0.4000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportSource, Version=13.0.4000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=13.0.4000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.4000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc, Version=13.0.4000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
      </assemblies>

 <buildProviders>
        <add extension=".rpt" type="CrystalDecisions.Web.Compilation.RptBuildProvider, CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.4000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
        <add extension=".rdlc" type="Microsoft.Reporting.RdlBuildProvider, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"/>
      </buildProviders>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just install the Crystal runtime 32 bits

Answer (score -1):

If you have the to your project and the Copy Local flag is in true, the solution should be just the project. That copy the DLL to the bin folder.