# Crystal Report : File not found exception

Tags: c#, visual-studio, crystal-reports

The solution cannot find the correct version of crystal report

I want to run a project which was developed in another system and I need to get it run in my system. There were some references already missing in the solution, So I downloaded the missing reference and added to the solution. The solution was having a missing reference to crystal report dlls So I downloaded the crystal report and added the dlls, the solution built just fine. But when it comes to crystal report it gives an exception that the file was not found. There is a mismatch between version of crystal report that I added as reference and version shown in exception. I don't have the old version of dll that the exception is referring to

[image]

This is the version of crystal report I've added

[image]

This is the exception I am getting

Can anyone tell me how to correct this version mismatch and correct this exception

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the 2000 assemblies and add the 3500 versions, check your app.config file.

Set the dll as the atribute "Copy Local" to **true**.

Also make sure you are running VS as Administrator.

As seen [here](https://answers.sap.com/questions/319000/sp21-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-crystaldecisi.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38025849/10191493).