# Crystal Reports - Connect to Data Source in another Project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2017, crystal-reports, sql-server-2014

I have a VS 2017 Solution (ASP.NET MVC5, C#) with several projects. One of the projects contain my Data Models, and I have created a separate project where all my Reports will be created. The reason why I have separate projects is to have smaller DLL files on live website.

To give you an idea, my solution contains the following projects:

- Pps.Admin
- Pps.Customer
- Pps.Data
- Pps.Reports
- Pps.User
- Pps.Web

I have a very complicated report, that collects data from various tables and stores them in 5 linked Report Tables. The problem I am having is that the Crystal Reports seem to pick up only the Data Sources in the "Pps.Reports" project, and should be looking at the "Pps.Data" project where all my Data Models are.

Is there a way I can include the "Pps.Data" project data sources, so that my Report can see the them?

Comment: A Data Report is RDLC file that is loaded in to the SQL Report Manager.  The RDLC is HTML format and can be viewed as text in not pad.  The RDLC has "COMMAND TEXT" which is the SQL QUERY.  The query will have a "FROM" indicating the SQL Table to extract the data.  So it looks like you need to pass the RDLC a parameter to select the COMMAND Text to use for the query.

Comment: Hello jdweng. Thank you for your reply. I understand what you say about RDLC, but I am using the Crystal Reports nuget package, not Microsoft Reporting. The report file has an ".rpt" extension, not ".rdlc".

I might just add that I use EF6 Code First to create my data models. And my issue is that Crystal Report Designer only looks in the project where the report is located for data sources.

So I was wondering if it is possible in some way to have Creystal Report Designer too for the data sources in my Pps.Data project, instead of, or in addition to my Pps.Reports project.

Comment: See following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23470453/how-to-dynamically-change-crystal-report-database-connection